# FullCalendar "Background Events"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

need a little help with something. I am using the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) library in my project. I would like to have the ability to render "background events". What I mean by this is to have `events` (identified by `event.title` or something of the like) that are just rendered behind other `events`. These "background-events" should not affect the stacking of current `events`.

I would like it to end up something like this:
[image]
Where the purple/blue event is the "background event", and the red one's are just regular `events`.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that full calendar 2.2 has something called [Background events](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.6/demos/background-events.html) What I can't figure out though is in this demo the 'background' is limiting it to the selection range of that day. Their demos are "interesting" but all you can do is drag that around or resize the event, but you can't resize outside of the background.

This may be something you want too though. I just wish they explained the use case for Background, and then I'd get the idea behind what they were thinking.